# Проверка нажатия Inline кнопок. Telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пытаюсь написать бота, который будет отправлять сообщения постоянно, не принимая текстовых сообщений от пользователя,а лишь будет реагировать на нажатия кнопок и команды /start в начале. Как сделать проверку нажатия Inline кнопки, чтобы последующие строки кода не выполнялись до их нажатия? Пробовал разделять код на несколько функций, но в таком случае боту так же приходится принимать какие-то сообщения от пользователя...

```
button1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 1)
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Какой-то текст", callback_data= "answer1")
item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Какой-то текст", callback_data= "answer2")

button1.add(item1, item2)

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Какой-то текст", reply_markup=button1)
sl(1)


#Здесь надо сделать проверку на нажатие перед выполнением
for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i > 4:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, line )
            sl(1)
```

Мне ниже подсказали засунуть условие `for` в функцию `callback_query_handler`   . Но что делать, если после создания первого сообщения с прикрепленными к нему кнопками, за ним должно выводиться еще одно, тоже с кнопками, но только после взаимодействия с первым?

```
button1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("text", callback_data= "ans1") 
button1.add(item1)

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "text", reply_markup=button1) 

button2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() 
item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("text", callback_data= "ans2") 
button2.add(item2) 

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "text", reply_markup=button2)
```

Comment: Так а в чем проблема не делать хендлеры которые реагируют на текст? Чисто команды и колбек хендлеры. Я не понимаю проблемы.

Comment: Мне в теории нужно использовать всего одну команду - это /start, и все. А так как Inline кнопки не отправляют сообщений в отличии от обычных, я не знаю как проверять их нажатие для продолжения отправки ботом новых сообщений с кнопками. Я отредачил вопрос, надеюсь он стал чуть понятнее и кто-нибудь да поможет...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну смотри, тебе не нужны месседж хендлеры если ты не намерен никак получать информацию от юзера в текстовом виде. Чтобы юзать только кобеки нужно передавать в кнопках колбек дату и на основании этого делать определенное поведение бота.
Ну и немного инфы как удобней делать фильтры.
Во первых есть вот эти:
text - колбек дата (или текст сообщения) равны тому что мы указали (text="4toto")
text_startwith - начинается с
text_endswith - заканчивается на
text_containt - имеет внутри то-то

Еще есть колбекдата точнее CallbackData. Это уже более продвинутый тип фильтрации хендлеров. Юзать их постоянно не очень удобно но для некоторых случаев подойдет.

Ну и вот немного кода

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.utils.callback_data import CallbackData

from data import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

# cd_action = CallbackData("prefix", "filter")
# фильтров может быть несколько
cd_action = CallbackData("cd_choto_tam", "data")


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton("text", callback_data="from_start"))
    await message.answer("text", reply_markup=markup)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="from_start")
async def callbacl_choto_tam(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    await call.message.edit_text(
        "text",
        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
            InlineKeyboardButton("text1", callback_data=cd_action.new(data="1")),
            InlineKeyboardButton("text2", callback_data=cd_action.new(data="2"))
        ))


# хендлер принимает только cd_action
# и вроде как и фильтр text_startswith="cd_choto_tam" тоже сработает
# доп инфа
# вот такой хендлер можно использовать для более подробной фильтрации колбек даты
# @dp.callback_query_handler(cd_action.filter(data="1"))
###
# хендлер ниже принимает нажатие кнопок сделаных в хендлере выше
@dp.callback_query_handler(cd_action.filter())
async def callbacl_choto_tam(call: types.CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    await call.answer()
    print(callback_data)
    # {'@': 'cd_choto_tam', 'data': '1'} при нажатии на text1


"""
#Второй вариант

@dp.callback_query_handler(text="from_start")
async def callbacl_choto_tam(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    await call.message.edit_text(
        "text",
        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
            InlineKeyboardButton("text", callback_data="go_to:1"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("text", callback_data="go_to:2")
        ))

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="go_to")
async def callbacl_choto_tam(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    if call.data.split(":")[1] == "1":
        pass
    else:
        pass
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

В вашем случае, если в функцию вы передаёте параметр `call`, тогда пример кода будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```py
if call.data == "answer1":
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i > 4:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, line)
            sl(1)
```